# How to create pagination in UITableViewController with table sections

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, pagination, parse-platform

I have Image shown in UITableViewCell and below I have 5 comments. Right now I implemented this using cell and UITableView inside that cell for comments. Comment number is hardcoded but can be less then 5.

With this kind of implementation I have performance issue ( everything stops for a second or so).

I could to this without a glitch using Table sections but I am not sure how to correctly implement this.

I am open to other suggestions as well.

I should mention that I am doing this in objecitve-c, I use Parse for database storage.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did not try it, but it might help

http://nsscreencast.com/episodes/8-automatic-uitableview-paging

Comment: Actually, I already have pagination with cells, and it's working fine... I am looking at table section pagination. Thanks for you answer

Comment: this post could help.. ctrl-F for 'pagination'

https://parse.com/questions/using-pfquerytableviewcontroller-for-uitableview-sections

Comment: Great, haven't encountered this article, will try it now :)